# SQL query interpretation

Tags: mysql, sql, bigdata

I have given an home assignment to explain the following query:

```
select
    date,
    country,
    count(*) as `result`
from (
    select
        user_id,
        event_date as date,
        any_value(geo.country) as country
    from `xxxx-android.events.all`
    where event_date between current_date - interval 2 day and current_date - interval 1 day
    group by user_id, date
)
group by date, country
order by date, count(*) desc
```

And I tried to replicate it in MySql with this [online editor](https://onecompiler.com/) using the following code :

```
CREATE TABLE events (
  user_id INTEGER,
  event_date DATE,
  country TEXT -- NOT NULL
);
-- insert some values
INSERT INTO events VALUES (1, '2022-1-9', 'USA');
INSERT INTO events VALUES (1, '2022-1-9', 'USA');
INSERT INTO events VALUES (1, '2022-1-10', 'USA');
INSERT INTO events VALUES (2, '2022-1-9', 'UK');
INSERT INTO events VALUES (2, '2022-1-10', 'UK');
INSERT INTO events VALUES (2, '2022-1-9', 'UK');
INSERT INTO events VALUES (3, '2022-1-9', 'USA');
INSERT INTO events VALUES (3, '2022-1-10', 'USA');
INSERT INTO events VALUES (3, '2022-1-10', 'USA');
INSERT INTO events VALUES (4, '2022-1-9', 'AUT');
INSERT INTO events VALUES (4, '2022-1-10', 'AUT');
INSERT INTO events VALUES (5, '2022-1-10', 'AUT');
INSERT INTO events VALUES (5, '2022-1-10', 'AUT');
INSERT INTO events VALUES (6, '2022-1-9', NULL);
INSERT INTO events VALUES (6, '2022-1-9', NULL);

-- fetch some values
-- SELECT * FROM events;

-- select curdate() - interval 2 day;
-- select curdate() - interval 1 day;


select
    event_date,
    country,
    count(*) as 'result'
from (

-- begin internal query
select
    user_id as user_id,
    event_date as event_date,
    any_value(country) as country
from events
    where event_date between curdate() - interval 2 day and curdate() - interval 1 day
group by user_id, event_date
-- end begin internal query
 
) as whatever
group by event_date, country
order by event_date, count(*) desc
```

And I get the following table :

```
Output:

event_date  country result
2022-01-09  USA       2
2022-01-09  UK        1
2022-01-09  AUT       1
2022-01-09  NULL      1
2022-01-10  USA       2
2022-01-10  AUT       2
2022-01-10  UK        1
```

Shouldn't the result count if a user enters multiple times a day? For example the user with id 1 entered 2 times in '2022-01-09' but in the output was only counted as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is implied by the term in the `Group BY`in the inner `SELECT`

you group by user id and events

```
group by user_id, event_date
```

But

```
user_id as user_id,
event_date as event_date,
any_value(country) as country
```

wouldn't show any duplicate Values see manual to [any_value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value)

> ```
> select
>     user_id as user_id,
>     event_date as event_date,
>     any_value(country) as country
> from events
>     where event_date between curdate() - interval 2 day and curdate() - interval 1 day
> group by user_id, event_date
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | event_date | country
> ------: | :--------- | :------
>       1 | 2022-01-09 | USA    
>       1 | 2022-01-10 | USA    
>       2 | 2022-01-09 | UK     
>       2 | 2022-01-10 | UK     
>       3 | 2022-01-09 | USA    
>       3 | 2022-01-10 | USA    
>       4 | 2022-01-09 | AUT    
>       4 | 2022-01-10 | AUT    
>       5 | 2022-01-10 | AUT    
>       6 | 2022-01-09 | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8c01ae535bd35157f17cadafebdea119)*

that is why the count is only 2 and not 3 for the 09.09.2022

Comment: Yes, if I don't use group by it returns the duplicates as well. Another question what would any_value do?

Comment: any_VALUE shows every  value in the column for the choosen group without duplicates. so the query doesn't count duplicates.

Comment: @dangr you should also take a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html to see why any_value is used and also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value